# Why the exif metadata doesn't show up?

Tags: java, metadata, exif

I'm using the javaxt-core library to extract the exif meta from the images. When I first did it, the script was working and I could see the data, but on the second image, which I tested it shows only null. Same situation with any image and with the first one, which I tested.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image("res/test.jpg");
     java.util.HashMap<Integer, Object> exif = image.getExifTags();

     System.out.println("New subfile type: " + exif.get(0x00FE));
     System.out.println("Subfile type: " + exif.get(0x00FF));
     System.out.println("Image Width: " + exif.get(0x0100));
     System.out.println("Image Length: " + exif.get(0x0101));
     System.out.println("Bits per sample: " + exif.get(0x0102));
     System.out.println("Compression: " + exif.get(0x0103));
     System.out.println("Photometric Interpretation: " + exif.get(0x0106));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your second image contains the metadata you're looking for?

Check it with a tool like [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

I don't know javaxt-core, but I do maintain a different Java image metadata library with Exif support, [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) which doesn't require you to know the numeric value of tags, for starters.